# Download APK using nodejs in playstore

Tags: node.js

How to download apk in playstore using nodejs **with out using any thrid party api** . can I use google api for download apk

Comment: APKs are hosted by Google Play. Node.js is for creating your own webserver to serve files. However, creating a node.js server is unnecessary for serving APK files because Google handles that via the Play store.

Comment: I am not saying creating nodejs server . I just need to download apk from google play store. and also @StephenTaylor nodejs is not creating any webserver . we can use nodejs to create webserver or any other application .Node.js is a JavaScript runtime built on Chrome's V8 JavaScript engine.